# Ruby forcing garbage collection not working as expected

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, finalizer

In the following code:

```
class ExampleClass
  def initialize
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, proc{puts 'dead'})
  end
end

ex = ExampleClass.new
ex = nil

GC.start

while true
  # the while loop is to prevent the program from terminate
  # if the program does terminate, the finalizer gets called in the end like expected
end
```

The finalizer here is never called and there is no output. I would have expected the garbage collector to collect `ex` since it has been dereferenced. Why is `GC.start` not forcing `ex` to be collected and causing the `finalizer to be called` immediately?

Comment: I'm seeing `dead` print if I close your code using control+c as well as if I replace the `while true end` with `exit`. I'm on Ruby 2.5.0-dev fwiw. What platform are you on?

Comment: I'm on eclipse using Ruby 2.4.0

Comment: oh, and does the finalizer work without the GC.start?

Comment: I'm wondering why the `dead` does not print right when I call `GC.start`. I put a while loop there to show that the program does not terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that when you create a new [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Proc.html#method-c-new) (`proc` just calls `Proc.new`, in [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-proc))

> Creates a new Proc object, bound to the current context.

Means that it's saving a reference to the `self` object and thus can never be de-referenced for the garbage collector to collect it. You should create the `proc` inside a class method instead so that the context becomes the class not the instance you're trying to destroy.

```
class ExampleClass
  def initialize
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, self.class.finalize)
  end

  def self.finalize
    proc { puts "dead" }
  end

end


ex = ExampleClass.new
# needed to do something with the object as well, not sure why,
# but it won't work without this line either
puts "object id = #{ex.object_id}"
ex = nil

GC.start
while true
end
```

and this outputs

```
object id = 70223915005060
dead
^Cexample.rb:20:in `<main>': Interrupt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I tried it and it even worked without the extra `puts "object id = #{ex.object_id}"`.

Comment: Ah, yeah I don't remember needing it previously, but it wasn't running for me without it, so something in my ruby implementation, I guess, but I mean, in real examples you're probably using the object for something anyway, not just instantiating things so that we can get a finalizer to run.