# GC.start doesn't seem to actually collect the garbage

Tags: ruby

I'm developing a class that has a finalizer method. In order to test the class, I want to run the garbage collector, then test some states to see if everything worked. However, I can't seem to actually get the garbage collected, so the finalization doesn't happen until the script ends. The following code shows the problem.

```
class FinalCall
    def initialize
        ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, proc { puts 'finalizing' })
    end
end

FinalCall.new
GC.start
puts 'done'
```

I had expected output like this:

```
finalizing
done
```

But I actually get this:

```
done
finalizing
```

What am I missing? How do you force GC to finalize everything that's out of scope?

Comment: The Ruby GC only collects things it can no longer "see anywhere" it's possible there's some reference to it still lurking. Try putting it in a method or something :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby forcing garbage collection not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175422/ruby-forcing-garbage-collection-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: The example in the post you reference doesn't work for me. Here's what ruby I'm using: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: @tscheingeld That question is almost line for line exactly identical to your question and is functionally identical. If there's something that differentiates your question from that question then you must explain that here. Otherwise, it's the same question and the vote to close this duplicate question remains.

Answer (score 2):

`GC.start` is not a guarantee that the garbage collector will run. It is only an advisory that it would be okay for your code if a GC happened at this particular point in time. Requiring the GC to run at a particular point in time would unreasonably constrain implementors. For example, it would be impossible to write a Ruby implementation for the JVM, the CLI, or the ECMAScript or PyPy platform, or to use frameworks like Eclipse OMR, since the GC is not under the control of the implementor.

There is no guarantee when a GC will happen. There is not even a guarantee that a GC will happen *at all*.

Therefore, there is also no guarantee about when or even if a finalizer will run.

Comment: OK, thanks. It would be nice if there were a way to force garbage collection, if only for testing purposes.

Comment: If you add a way to force GC to Ruby, then you would need to abandon 5-6 of the currently 8 existing Ruby implementations, since it would be impossible for them to implement. Pretty much *no* platform implements this feature, so any implementation that relies on an underlying platform such as TruffleRuby, JRuby, Opal, RubyOMR, or IronRuby *cannot* implement Ruby. Also, any implementation that relies on an external high-performance GC will not be implementable. In fact, it would be pretty much impossible to implement a high-performance Ruby implementation *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

While Jörg is correct, you have an additional problem here: Your finalizer proc creates a closure over `self` which increments the reference count and then prevents your object from being collected!

The correct approach is to use a class method which creates a proc which does not close over instances. For example:

```
class IncorrectFinalCall
  def initialize
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer( self, proc { puts 'finalizing IncorrectFinalCall' } )
  end
end

class FinalCall
  def initialize
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer( self, self.class.finalizer )
  end

  def self.finalizer
    proc { puts 'finalizing FinalCall' }
  end
end

10.times do
  IncorrectFinalCall.new
  FinalCall.new
end
GC.start
puts 'done'
```

Resulting in:

```
ruby gc.rb
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
finalizing FinalCall
done
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
finalizing IncorrectFinalCall
```

Comment: I find it interesting that either finalizer is run at all in this example. I would have thought that if the process exits without running out of memory, it would simply let the OS de-allocate the memory and *never* run the GC nor the finalizer. This makes short-lived scripts much more expensive than I originally thought. It would be interesting to compare the behavior of different implementations here.

Comment: Defined finalizers are run for all objects on VM shutdown, per the [Kernel#exit](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) documentation.